# Update only the date from datetime - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with datatype Date time and so contains value such as:`06-FEB-12 02.39.11.000000000 PM`. I wanted to only modify the date for all the rows that are dated `06-FEB-12` to `25-JAN-12` preserving the time.

Can I do the same through an update query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the data type.  You state the the column is a `DATE` but the sample data you provided has fractional seconds which implies a `TIMESTAMP`.

You can subtract exactly 12 days from all the rows that have a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` on February 6, 2012 which will yield `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values on January 25, 2012.

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET column_name = column_name - interval '12' day
 WHERE trunc( column_name ) = date '2012-02-06';
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. Yes the column is a Timestamp(6) format. When I am running the query, I get the error `missing or invalid <datetime field>
30089. 00000 -  "missing or invalid <datetime field>"
*Cause:    A <datetime field> (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND) is
           expected but not found, or a <datetime field> specified the
           <end field> in an <interval qualifier> is more significant
           than its <start field>.`

Comment: Got it! Can you please change the query to have the interval literal as `day` instead of `days`. I do not have edit privileges

Comment: @darkie15 - Yeah, sorry about that typo.  Updated the answer to fix it.